# Passing inline function definition as input parameter to a function

Tags: function, swift

Say, I have a function which accepts a function as one of the input parameters:

```
// modify passed string
func modifyString(paramString: String, modificationFunction: String -> String) -> String {
    return modificationFunction(paramString)
}
```

Now I can define a function like this:

```
func addLearningSuffix(inputString: String) -> String {
    var returnString = inputString + " is learning swift"
    return returnString
}
```

And use it like this:

```
// adds suffix - is learning swift
modifyString("Miraaj",  addLearningSuffix) // returns "Miraaj is learning swift"
```

In above case I just passed function name - **addLearningSuffix** as input parameter to the function - **modifyString**, but what if I want to define function in the same line while passing it as input parameter.

I know that functions are special case of closures, so I can pass inline closure like this:

```
// adds prefix - Miraaj
modifyString("is learning swift",{
    (inputString: String) -> String in
    let result = "Miraaj " + inputString
    return result // returns "Miraaj is learning swift"
    })
```

or like this:

```
modifyString("is learning swift"){
    (inputString: String) -> String in
    let result = "Miraaj " + inputString
    return result
    }
```

But why I can't pass inline function definition like this:

```
modifyString(" is learning swift", func addSomeOtherPrefix(inputString: String) -> String{
    return "Miraaj" + inputString
})
```

Trying which compiler complains :(

Please suggest if I am doing any thing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about the difference between declaring an object and then using it:

```
var a = 100
abs(a)
```

vs using it directly:

```
abs(100)
```

Same difference applies between declaring then using a function:

```
func talk(x: String) { return x + " is talking" }
doThis(talk)
```

vs using it directly:

```
doThis( { x: String -> return x + " is talking" } )
```

Writing

```
doThis( func talk(x: String) { return x + " is talking" } )
```

is like writing

```
abs(var a = 100)
```

which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but avoid the `func` keyword, that is, avoid declaring a fun, but use the anonymous nature of closures:

```
modifyString(" is learning swift", { inputString in "Miraaj" + inputString })
```

See http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com